# Keeping formatting of text document after being manipulated with JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, ckeditor

I am trying to use JavaScript to manipulate and change font and font size from a page of text from a word processor (such as Google Docs or Word) inputted by a user, by an HTML word processor (CKEditor).  However, after manipulation of font size, when displaying the text into an HTML text field, much of the document formatting is lost such as no indentation, spaces at the end of the line being deleted, titles are not centered.

Is there a way to correctly format a text document using purely HTML?
I have not found a function in CKEditor that allows me to change the font or font size on call within it, or any other HTML word processor for that matter.

Here's the code that manipulates the text, then pastes it into the HTML text area.

```html
editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
var edata = editor.getData();
edata = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().getText();

var sin = replaced_text;
var sout = "";
var i;
for(i = 0 ; i < sin.length; i++)    {
if(sin.charAt(i) == ",")
{        sout += '<span class=ef>' + sin.charAt(i) + '</span>'        }
else if(sin.charAt(i) == ".")        {        sout += '<span class=ef>' + sin.charAt(i) + '</span>'        }
else if(sin.charAt(i) == " " && sin.charAt(i+1) == " ")        {        sout += 'span class = of>' + sin.charAt(i) + sin.charAt(i+1) + '</span>'        }
else if(sin.charAt(i) == " "){          sout += '<span class=of>' + sin.charAt(i) + '</span>'       }
else       {sout+= '<span class=if>' + sin.charAt(i) + '</span>'}
}

var data = editor.dataProcessor.toDataFormat( sout );
document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = data;
editor.setData(data);
editor.updateElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's helpful for you [markedJS](https://github.com/chjj/marked).

MarkedJS can parse markdown text, you can use it to marked your text so that keeps text formate